# what does /* does to a row in java?

Tags: java

In a java preparation exam there is a question which is " what happens if we put /* instead of // before a comment". I tried it and it was an error.

Is /* actually do with a row ? Is it useful anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: When you use `/*` you have to close it with `*/`, read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm

Comment: Read more here :http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141999.html#385

Comment: A line of code is not a 'row'. Don't misuse standard terminology. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: This is a beginner's interview question: `//` plus rest of the line is free _comment_, not turned into code, just as `/*` until `*/` in the code is a (mulit-line) _comment_ too.

Answer (score 2):

// is for single line comment
/* is for multiline comments

Java's single line comment starts with two forward slashes with no white spaces (//) and lasts till the end of line. If the comment exceeds one line then put two more consecutive slashes on next line and continue the comment.

Eg-

```
if(x < y) 
{ // begin if block
 x = y;
 y = 0;
} // end 
//if block
```

Java's multi-line or slash-star or traditional comment is a piece of text enclosed in slash-star `/*` and star-slash `*/`.There should be no white space between slash and star

Eg-

```
if(x < y) 
{ /* begin
  if blockz*/
  x = y;
  y = 0;
} /* end
 if block*/
```

Answer (score 0):

> what happens if we put /* instead of // before a comment"

Then everything (every line of code) after `/*` will be treated as comments, including all the closing brackets for your main and class.

> I tried it and it was an error.

The error occurs because all your closing brackets were commented away as well. It was not directly caused by `/*`

Answer (score -1):

> What happens if we put /* instead of // before a comment ?

The remainder of the code past `/*` will be treated as a comment until a closing `*/` is encountered.

```
/*
All of this
text is a
comment
*/
```

`//` indicates a single line comment, so only the remainder of the line is treated as a comment

```
int x = 0; // This is a comment
This is not a comment
```